# Cannot Examine Function Argument via Xcode 6.4's Debug Pane

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am working with iOS 8's Core Bluetooth API. I have written some simple Swift code that creates a Central Manager and that implements the CBManager & CBPeripheral protocols. When the callbacks are executed they perform logging:

1. 2015-09-04 14:08:33.719 CentralManager - Did update state to Powered on
2. 2015-09-04 14:08:33.745 CentralManager - Did discover peripheral: CBPeripheral: 0x1700f5080, identifier = 3DD113C3-D175-7374-CF88- F471BB470169, name = Apple TV, state = disconnected
3. 2015-09-04 14:08:33.955 CentralManager - Did connect peripheral: CBPeripheral: 0x1700f5080, identifier = 3DD113C3-D175-7374-CF88-F471BB470169, name = Apple TV, state = connected
4. 2015-09-04 14:08:34.462 Peripheral - Did discover service: CBService: 0x174075600, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Continuity
5. 2015-09-04 14:08:34.582 Peripheral: Did discover characteristic for service Continuity : ()

Everything looks good. As you can see, log statements 2 and 3 print the value of the CBPeripheral argument that was passed to the callback function. I am using Swift's string interpolation capability to accomplish this - ex. "The value is \(peripheral)".

Now for the problem: When I set a breakpoint in one of the callback functions and examine the CBPeripheral argument via Xcode's debug pane, I am not able to view any of the values that are revealed by the logging statements. When I expand the CBPeripheral (i.e. click on the triangle next to it) I see that it is a CBPeer. When I expand the CBPeer I see that it is an NSObject. But, no variables or properties are revealed.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Cheers, Robert

Comment: Do you have your optimization flag set to None for debug?

Comment: Hi Dave. Yes, it is set to none. I wonder if this is a Swift thing? The word "bridging" keeps coming to mind.